# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on JavaEE project code

Tags: java, mysql

These days I do exercise about JDBC.When the Java project connect the MySQL，then it's Ok.But the JavaEE project which run on MyEclipse cann't connect to MySQL,these is the error messages:

```
严重: create connection error
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2397)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.connection_connect(FilterChainImpl.java:142)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.stat.StatFilter.connection_connect(StatFilter.java:211)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.connection_connect(FilterChainImpl.java:136)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidAbstractDataSource.createPhysicalConnection(DruidAbstractDataSource.java:1271)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidAbstractDataSource.createPhysicalConnection(DruidAbstractDataSource.java:1325)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource$CreateConnectionThread.run(DruidDataSource.java:1215).
```

> ***The import thing:I try to grand,restart the mysql and so on.But all of them are failed.***

Comment: Maybe user/password is wrong

Comment: You should put relevant code rather then just error log. Not possible to be the Oracle and predict what might be wrong. Downvoting.

Comment: Following are the code of JDBC:

Comment: http://bbs.csdn.net/topics/391818820

Answer (score 2):

MySql default password is `root` try it, or using the "" for password.

Comment: stop the server and Restart then try it

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone.I solve my problem.Followings are the ways:

(1:To install a newest MyEclipse software.)

2.To install a newest Tomcat7.0.64.(Warning:this is the most important way I have to solve my problem).